# how to validate recaptcha and procedd with the rest of my validation (other script)

Tags: php, validation, recaptcha

I have a form (login.php) to get the username and password that I have to validate (index.php). This works fine but now I need to add recaptcha to prevent bots.

I followed this tutorial and looks fine but my question (as far I can understand the code) is: how pass now the login parameters to the validation (index.pxp) only when I know the recaptcha validated fine (success).

Tutorial:  http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024

My login.php is something like this:

```
<?php // To learn how this works
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
}

require_once "recaptchalib.php";

$mysecret = "6LeR9C8oDC4ekXQ4";
$myresponse = null;
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($mysecret);

if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) { // si se detecta la respuesta como enviada
$myresponse = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php /*<form action="index.php" method="post">*/ ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input  name="from" value="true" type="hidden" />
<table align="center">
<tr valign="top">
  <td>Nombre de usuario:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="login" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
  <td>Contraseña:</td>
  <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeR9idR-NV-NFWCsdfsyJu"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input class="button" type="submit" value=" Enviar " /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advise is appreciated

Comment: To help you, we can take a look to your form processor (page verify if user/password are correct)

Comment: I am afraid I cannot share it because is a library from sitepoint I got with the book: Build Your Own Database Driven Web Site Using PHP & MySQL (companion code) The main thing looks like:

    $db       = & new MySQL($host, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);       // Instantiate MySQL connection
    $auth     = & new Auth ($db, 'login.php', 'secretphrase');        // Instantiate the Auth class
    $userdata = & new User ($db);

The Auth class decides and then if the user/pwd combo is not correct, they transfer the control to login.php

Comment: You are using recaptcha v1 and the php library which is deprecated and no longer works with newly generated site keys. You will need to check [the docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) for how to set up the new version.

Comment: @Ryan89 nop, I am using version 2. Why do you said that?. Thanks for your help

Comment: @notuo Version 2 is not compatible with the php recaptcha library `recaptchalib.php`, but I guess as long as its working properly for you then thats good.

Comment: Yes, I had code for version 1 and with that worked. I deleted and modify my code and is working fine. Thanks for pointing that. @Rayan89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, was more easy than I thought. Simply instead of action="" the actual target="index.php" works fine. There, I just checked for the proper response and I have everything I need.

I don't know if I misread the documentation or there is none about this.